# Envoy: REST gateway + multiple GRPC clusters

Tags: http, grpc, gateway, api-gateway, envoyproxy

I'm trying to config envoy as rest api gateway with multiple grpc servers and have a problem with routing. The only way to match endpoint to grpc cluster, that i've found is to match via request header (http request `/first` must be resolved by `first` cluster, `/second` - by `second`):

```
...
routes:
  - match:
      prefix: "/"
      headers:
        - name: x-service
          exact_match: "first"
    route:
      cluster: first
  
  - match:
      prefix: "/"
      headers:
        - name: x-service
          exact_match: "second"
    route:
      cluster: second

...
```

But, in this case i need to set custom header 'x-service' at the client (frontend). This looks like a bad idea, 'couse frontend shouldn't know anything about backend infrastructure.

Is there any other way to match http route with grpc service? Or, can i set such headers somewhere in envoy?

Comment: Could you share what methods are implemented in your two gRPC services (first and second) ? Are they the same ? Is there only one method per gRPC service ? Also, if you choose to redirect `/first` methods to first cluster, what is the difference with the `x-service` header ? In both cases, the frontend always need to know the backend infrastructure (first is added to the path instead of a header).

Answer (score 0):

The Envoy configuration pasted below registers a HTTP listener on port `51051` that proxies to `helloworld.Greeter` service in the cluster `grpc1` on port `50051` and `bookstore.Bookstore` service in the cluster `grpc2` on port `50052` by using the gRPC route as the match prefix.

This ensures clean segregation of responsibilities and isolation since the client will not need to inject custom HTTP headers to make multi-gRPC cluster routing work.

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener1
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 51051 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.file
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.file.v3.FileAccessLog
              path: /dev/stdout
          stat_prefix: grpc_json
          codec_type: AUTO
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              # NOTE: by default, matching happens based on the gRPC route, and not on the incoming request path.
              # Reference: https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter#route-configs-for-transcoded-requests
              - match: { prefix: "/helloworld.Greeter" }
                route: { cluster: grpc1, timeout: 60s }
              - match: { prefix: "/bookstore.Bookstore" }
                route: { cluster: grpc2, timeout: 60s } 
 clusters:
  - name: grpc1
    connect_timeout: 1.25s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: grpc1
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 50051
  - name: grpc2
    connect_timeout: 1.25s
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.http.v3.HttpProtocolOptions
        explicit_http_config:
          http2_protocol_options: {}
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: grpc2
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 127.0.0.1
                port_value: 50052
```

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/test/proto/helloworld.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello(HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/say"
    };
  }
}
```

https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/blob/main/test/proto/bookstore.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

package bookstore;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/api/httpbody.proto";
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

// A simple Bookstore API.
//
// The API manages shelves and books resources. Shelves contain books.
service Bookstore {
  // Returns a list of all shelves in the bookstore.
  rpc ListShelves(google.protobuf.Empty) returns (ListShelvesResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/shelves"
    };
  }
...
```